# wit.ai Is it possible to download the inbox data?

Tags: wit.ai

I'm creating a complex chatbot which will need user testing. It might be useful to be able to download the inbox data as json for intents that are not understood, rather than dealing with it in on the online wit user interface. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

(Disclaimer: I work on Wit)

We currently don't offer an API for the Inbox (fetch/validate).
Can you describe your use case a little more?

Notably, would you build a UI similar to the Inbox? how would you handle entity tagging?

Comment: I'm currently looking into ways of dealing with lots of inbox messages. For example to see how often certain words appear in the entire list that we might want to deal with. Or list intents that have missing keywords. I'm not sure how feasible going through thousands of inbox messages without sorting them would be.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I added that to our roadmap, but it is not our highest priority. Until we provide an official public API, you may want to look at how the UI displays the Logs section.